# Is Visual Studio Code really free?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is Visual Studio Code really free?
https://code.visualstudio.com/License

- 1.b. : So we can only demo not develop?
- 7. "The software is licensed, not sold." : What does it means?
- 10. "the International Traffic in Arms Regulations" : Oh. That means we can't use it right?

So in a way it is as same as sublime. It is free but you have to buy it. right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a legal issue than a technical issue. Apart from that this is highly opinion-based, since you do not define what you actually mean by "free".

Comment: You seem to be completely misreading 1.b for starters. It says *"in addition to..., you can __also__ use it for demoing."* If you're actually concerned about this stuff, you need to actually read it. Also, what ^ he said. What does "free" mean?

Comment: We can't possibly tell if the US export restrictions apply to you; we don't know anything about you.

Comment: The last two points are general software licensing questions anyway. You'll find the same language in the Microsoft Windows license, so it isn't an issue specific to developers anyway.

Comment: Everything has a license. Nothing is truly "free". So you need to specify what you mean by "free". For example, some people consider GPL to be "free" - some consider it extremely restrictive. If you don't specify a license yourself, you delegate to whatever a given country has as the default (usually very restrictive as well). In this case, there's nothing special - all of those are pretty standard legalese. For example, "the software is licensed, not sold" simply means that you do not *own* the software - you cannot resell it, or claim it as yours, for example.

Comment: Thanks to all. means a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> Visual Studio Code is free and available on your favorite platform — Linux, OS X, and Windows. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx

So **yes**, this software is really free because you can use it for zero price (but not with the rights to modify and redistribute it).